# Odd script being sourced, no idea where from

Tags: php, html, wordpress

While troubleshooting my site I have ran into this error.

> "This page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources"

I am slowly learning to head to the Google developer console, which I found...

> (program):1 Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://www.thepixelfoundry.net/main/' was loaded over HTTPS, but
>   requested an insecure script
>   'http://api.sitestate.ru/scripts/stat/sitestate.js?r29'. This request
>   has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

This is my first Wordpress theme, as I built this page in order to better learn Wordpress. I have no idea what i sourcing that script.

I have checked my:

- functions.php
- header
- footer
- index

when I googled the scripts domain as the .ru already raised a red flag I received a warning from google questioning my computers recent traffic.

now im terrified....

How can I find this script? I have also installed Sucuri on the Wordpress side...and everything seems clean with a scan.

Comment: Using any plugins? Search the contents of all files in your plugins folder.

Comment: Unless you've intentionally installed a plugin that uses this, looks like you've been PWN-ed.

Comment: I no longer see the error on your page however I do expect that this is a file placed on your site maliciously and looks as though (at the very least) it's a redirect script to send visitors from your site to another one when they load the page. Securi SHOULD have found this but if it did not then contact them, ask them to take another look, and get them to clean it up for you. It does appear that you may have removed the file however see if they can help you with closing up whatever exploit that was used to add this to your page.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error in console, after I installed [Ace Stream Web Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ace-stream-web-extension/mjbepbhonbojpoaenhckjocchgfiaofo?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with it on remote server, then download all WP files and folders to your local machine and use "Search from all files" function. It is included in most text editors (Sublime, Notepad++, Brackets, etc.). Then you can track where this code comes from. When it comes from certain plugin you can disable the plugin. Or just remove that code.

But you should search, where that code get in your WP in first place. Is it some uploaded file that's supposed to be filename.jpg but is filename.jpg.php or comes from plugin or theme.

(I'd comment it but too low rep :/ )